# Disk latency after upgrade Linux 6 to 7

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, oracle-linux

[image]

Using Oracle Rack on 2 nodes, After upgrade Linux 6 to 7, I can see a noticeable increase in the Disk Latency metric on both nodes of the DB server, any idea of what parameter or setting I have to set?

[image]